# Is it really practical to use URLs instead of ids in a REST API

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design

The proper design of REST APIs seems to be a controversial topic. As far as I understand it, the purist approach with regard to ids would be that the URL is the only identifier of a resource for the outside world, so neither does the client have to interpret the URL in any way (e.g. knowing that the latest segment is the id) nor does the id have to be included explicitly in the representation returned for a simple GET request.

At first sight this seems to be a good rule because the client does not have to care about generating URLs based on ids, it's just the same thing. The id tells you how to retrieve the resource. However, I doubt that this is really applicable in practice. Some concerns that come to my mind:

- What if the URL changes because of a new API version (given that it is part of the URL)
- or the protocol changes from http to https.
- or the application even moves to another domain for whatever reason
- Short Ids are handy for referencing resources in parameters. This would not be possible: `/books?author=short.author.id`

It just puts too much information into an id that does not really belong there because the ide should not be interpreted by any consumer in such a way.

Is this really done in practice? Are there examples of popular public APIs applying this pattern? Or maybe I don't understand it correctly and this is not what REST purists advocate?

Comment: There's some good books for your question: Irresistible APIs, API Management: An Architect's Guide to Developing and Managing APIs, Creating Maintainable APIs: A Practical, Case-Study Approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Hypermedia Driven RESTFul APIs. In HATEOAS, URIs are discoverable (and not documented) so that they can be changed. That is, unless they are the very entry points into your system ([Cool URIs](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), the only ones that can be hard-coded by clients) - and you shouldn't have too many of those if you want the ability to evolve the rest of your system's URI structure in the future. This is in fact one of the most [useful](https://morethancoding.com/2011/09/07/uri-construction-give-it-a-rest/) features of REST.

For the remaining non-Cool URIs, they can be changed over time, and your API documentation should spell out the fact that they should be discovered at runtime through hypermedia traversal.

Looking at the [Richardson's Maturity Model (**level 3**)](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), this would be where links come into play. For example, from the top level, say /api/version(/1), you would discover there's a link to the groups. Here's how this could look in a tool like [HAL Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser):

Root:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/root"
    },
    "api:group-add": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group"
    },
    "api:group-search": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sort={sort}"
    },
    "api:group-by-id": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group/{id}" (OR "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group?id={id}")
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage here would be that the client would only need to know the relationship (link) name (well obviously besides the resource structure/properties), while the server would be mostly free to alter the relationship (and resource) url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, great references! With regard to the question: So you are saying that URLs should explicitly not be used as ids because they should be free to change?

Comment: @lex82 - There is actually no right or wrong regarding REST and URI design. It boils down to personal preferences actually, and of course on your particular requirements. Most APIs are fine stopping at level 2 of REST, because the overhead (both server & client-wise) added by level 3 outweighs the potential advantages.

Comment: Ok, I got that. However, what I understood from your answer and other posts I read is that it is rarely a good id that the resource URL is the *only* identifier passed to the client and something like `{ "id": 7, "href": "..." }` is perfectly fine.